# BASH Linux Run code for all file extensions ".fal"

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I am not a Linux user, so bash and shell are new for me.
I need a code that runs 2 scripts for all file extensions ".fal" that are located in the folder(and sub-folders preferably) that I run the code in.

E.g:

```
dos2unixfortxtandfal """""""that code runs for all files in the folder already
and 
for all ".fal" files in this folder,
Do 

eine_fal_macher (here the .fal files 1 by one) Versuch.txt
Done
```

> 1. eine_fal_marcher --> this is the script that runs in the moment only once
> 2. (here the .fal files 1 by one) --> this is input file 1
> 3. Versuch.txt--> this is input file 2 (same for all) (from the same
>      folder)
>
> In the end I want to do the following in the terminal:
>   frdc09927:\Frdc09927\z183464\DOE_Wellen\21a>
>   frdc09927:\Frdc09927\z183464\DOE_Wellen\21a>script.bash   --> Enter
>   frdc09927:\Frdc09927\z183464\DOE_Wellen\21b>script.bash   --> Enter
>   frdc09927:\Frdc09927\z183464\DOE_Wellen\21c>script.bash   --> Enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -name \*.fal -exec eine_fal_macher {} Versuch.txt \;
```

This runs for all *.fal files in the current directory and its subdirectories. Use `-maxdepth 1` as first option to limit it to the current directory only, or give a different working directory than `.` to have `find` search somewhere else. `{}` is replaced with the "found" filename, honoring things like spaces in the filename automatically.

I could start explaining `find` at this point, but you should *really* rather have a look at `man find` instead. This tool is *extremely* powerful, and can reduce rather complex problems (like acting on the age of files, their owners etc.) to a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for i in `ls *.fal`; do command1 $i && command2 $i; done
```

command2 is only executed for a specific file if command1 does not return an errorcode

Comment: Fails for filenames with spaces in them.

Comment: As said it will fail for files with spaces and `ls` is unnecessary: the shell will expand `*.fal`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the requirement, but here goes (trying to follow your pseudo code):

```
for FILE in `find . -name "*.fal"`
do   
  eine_fal_macher "${FILE}" Versuch.txt 
done
```

Comment: Fails for filenames with spaces in them. (Sorry. ;-) )